# UITextView in UITableViewCell not showing up if not "loaded" before typing on a UITextField before

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, uitextview

I have a form on an XCode Project using `UITableView` with Swift, where the first section of the form are `UITextView` in a `UITableViewCell`, and on the last cell is a `UITextView` with a height of 300, and constraints of 0 to the top, bottom, right, and left of the `UITableViewCell`. The form is bigger than the screen height. If you type on a `UITextField` without scrolling to the bottom and show the `UITextView` before, the `UITextView` goes missing and leaves a gap. (Screehshot attached below). I am using static cells, so I'm not calling the `TableView` functions.[image: How it is supposed to show]

[image: How it shows up]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

EDIT: Screenshots of dummy form. It has a `navigationController` with large titles, which makes the notes section not show on screen when loaded

[image: First section]
[image: Second section]

Comment: "I am using static cells, so I'm not calling the TableView functions."  Why do you even use a table view, then?  Wouldn't it be easier if you just put everything in a scroll view?

Comment: Screen shots are not clear... Where you are taking Textfield..?

Comment: @ElTomato I like the way forms look in  the tableview format

Comment: @ManishMahajan I had to cover some information, but the TextFields are on top of the form, further up than what is shown covered in the screehshots

Comment: @FrankFabregat2 Use dummy data, your question is not understandable... If its form implementation then use of TableView is just useless. Use scrollview

Comment: @ManishMahajan I added screenshots of a dummy copy of the form, of which the original has large titles in the navigation controller

Comment: Either share that dummy project created or please add some required code

Comment: @iOSGeek What code would you need to see?

Comment: How do you Deque tableCells and are they Different cell Xibs ?

Comment: @iOSGeek I am not dequeing the tableCells. They are static cells I dragged labels, textfields, switches, steppers, and a textview in the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I changed the size of the UITableViewCell to fit the UITextArea, and remove the height constraint to the UITextArea